# How can I register a recursive `load-path`?

Tags: emacs

After downloading an elisp package,

```
~/elisp/yaml-mode-master/
```

and with

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/elisp" load-path))
```

I find it necessary to `ln -s`

```
 ~/elisp/yaml-mode.el -> ~/elisp/yaml-mode-master/yaml-mode.el
```

so that a given `.el` package is found.

How can I register a recursive `load-path`, one that would find all `.el` files rooted at `~/elisp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path`, eg.

```
(let ((default-directory (expand-file-name "~/path/to/elisp")))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

Comment: Such a long name, for what must be a frequently needed function? That's a bit odd. Or is it the case that melpa has overtaken the Emacs world and those still downloading and saving packages manually deserve it?

Comment: Yea the builtin package system reigns supreme, but you should only need to call this function once or twice in your init -- I use during compilation for all my personal packages/configs and I would imagine a lot of emacs hackers do as well